# how do i print Z shape of "*" in shell script?

Tags: shell

this is the code i used to print z shape of "*" in java,  how can i print this on shell script ?

```
import java.util.*;

public class ZShape {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
  int n = input.nextInt(); 

  for (int x = 0; x <= n; x++) {
     for (int y = n; y >= 1; y--) {
        if (y > x) {
           System.out.print("* ");
        }
        else
           System.out.print(" ");
     } 
     System.out.println(); 
  }      
 }
}
```

Comment: Depends which shell. If you want to scar yourself for the rest of your life, start with `tcsh`.

Answer (score 1):

Lame (but easy) answer using `banner` and `tr`:

```
banner z | tr '#' '*'
```

Output:

```
 ******
     *
    *
   *
  *
 ******
```

See also: [How do I print 'block' letters in the terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287652/how-do-i-print-block-letters-in-the-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

You will use:

- the [`read` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read) for user input
- [`for` loops](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Loops_.28while.2C_until_and_for.29)
- [`if` statements](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29)
- and the shell's [builtin `printf` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf)